# como convertir en variables PHP los resultados de un array de multiples filas desde MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estimados de antemano agradezco sus aportes, estoy atascado en una logica que probablemente para muchos de ustedes es bastante simple y es la siguiente:
Tengo una tabla en MySQL y de ella obtengo un numero de registros asociados a la identificación del usuario así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, lo que deseo hacer es obtener los resultados de la columna "saldo_credito" para guardarlos en variables sobre PHP ya que debo realizar algunas operaciones sobre ellos, no obstante al realizar una consulta preparada usando FetchAll obtengo todo el array pero no tengo clara la logica para interactuar con el array de forma tal que pueda obtener estos resultados en forma de variables independientes, a manera de ejemplo lo que quisiera llegar a obtener es lo siguiente:

```
$var1=saldo_credito[0];
$var2=saldo_credito[1];
$var3=saldo_credito[2];
```

Nuevamente todos sus aportes son bienvenidos y agradecidos de mi parte. Un saludo

Anexo la porción de codigo que estoy utilizando para llegar a obtener el resultado requerido:

```
<?php
$ob1="";$ob2="";$ob3="";$ob4="";
$id=1111111;
$busqueda=$id;
try{    include("conexion2.php");                               
$base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $base->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      
$sql="SELECT identificacion, saldo_credito, id_reg FROM `t_nextracto` WHERE identificacion=? ORDER BY id_reg ASC";
        //variable $resultado que almacena PDO statement
        $stmt=$base->prepare($sql);
        //ejecutar la funcion
        $result=$stmt->execute(array($busqueda));
        $rows=$stmt->fetchAll();
        //Acá no se como generar la rutina de codigo para tomar los datos como variables.
        print_r($rows);


        $stmt->closecursor();                           
        }catch(exception $e)
            {
                die('Error: ' . $e->GetMessage());                      
            }finally{
                $base=null;
        }

?>
```

Comment: Agrega el código php donde obtienes los resultados y con gusto te puedo colaborar.

Comment: ¿Por qué pusiste la etiqueta `mysqli`?  PDO y mysqli  son dos cosas distintas, no se deberían mezclar esas etiquetas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partiendo de lo que ya tienes hecho y suponiendo que no tienes ningún error al consultar a base de datos;

Hace falta pasarle un parametro al metodo `fetchAll` para generar objetos los cuales tendran los nombres de las columna de tu consulta;

```
$rows=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

De esta manera ya puedes iterar todo el resultado de tu consulta ya que obtuviste los resultados como objetos;

```
foreach($rows as $datos){
 echo $datos->identificacion;
 echo $datos->saldo_credito;
 echo $datos->id_reg;
}
```

De esta manera imprimes en pantalla lo que obtienes en tu consulta, de igual manera puedes asignar cada resultado a una variable o como desees.

Te agrego la documentacion oficial si deseas conocer mas; http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php

Atendiendo a tu comentario en mi respuesta, para guardar todos en un arreglo (es lo que propones en tu ejemplo) lo puedes hacer dentro del mismo ciclo agregando un contador;

```
$contador = 0;
 foreach($rows as $datos){

     $var[$contador] $datos->saldo_credito;
     $contador++;

    }
print_r($var);
```

Comment: Estimado Albert gracias por tu valioso aporte, haciendo referencia a tu ultimo comentario, en efecto usando este ciclo puedo imprimir en pantalla los resultados del arreglo, pero como podría guardar en dos variables distintas el campo saldo_credito ?, puesto que se requieren para realizar operaciones posteriores con ellas. Esa es mi duda principal con respecto a ello y agradezco si me puedes dar luz con el tema. De antemano gracias y un saludo ;)

Comment: Bueno @MauroCV08 realmente no necesitas tenerlo guardado en variables ya que tienes objetos y puedes acceder a ellos independiente del ciclo de la siguiente manera, `$rows[0]->saldo_credito` para el primer elemento, `$rows[1]->saldo_credito`  para el segundo y así sucesivamente.

Comment: Estimado Albert, muchas gracias por tu aporte, en verdad me aclaraste la duda que tenía y resolviste mi consulta. Te agradezco mucho y estoy seguro que volveré a consultarlos con otras preguntas espero mas desafiantes en el futuro ;). Un saludo cordial.

Comment: @MauroCV08 te pondré en los favoritos!